# No service for type 'Type' has been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I have a database context that I am registering and seeding. However, I get the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No service for type
> 'AnnouncementContext' has been registered.'

**DB registering/seeding**

```
private static void SeedDatabase(IHost host)
        {
            var scopeFactory = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
            using var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();
            var announcementContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AnnouncementContext>(); // exception occurs here

            if (announcementContext.Database.EnsureCreated()) {
                try {
                    SeedData.Initialize(announcementContext);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    var logger = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "A database seeding error occurred.");
                    ErrorLogger.logError(ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Context class**

```
public class AnnouncementContext : DbContext {
        public AnnouncementContext(DbContextOptions<AnnouncementContext> options)
            : base(options) {
        }

        public DbSet<Announcement> Announcements { get; set; }
    }
```

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET (.NET Framework) or ASP.NET Core (.NET Core)?

Comment: Obvious question: have you registered `AnnouncementContext`?

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidelines on posting code and [edit] question to include service initialization portions where you register that class so someone can see what went wrong there. Without that question is not answerable .

Answer (score 2):

The code in your `DB registering/seeding` section is not registering any DB or DbContext. It is trying to get a reference of *already* registered DbContext (in your case `AnnouncementContext`). So, the question is, have you already registered it? The error message indicates, you have not.

In most common scenario, you are supposed to register the `AnnouncementContext` in the `ConfigureServices()` method of the `Startup` class like -

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();

    // this is the DbContext registration code
    services.AddDbContext<AnnouncementContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"));
}
```

For more on this - [DbContext in dependency injection for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core)